# MySQL information.schema.tables shows create_time later than update_time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, information-schema

I've checked [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html), but couldn't find anything that could explain this.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE table_schema='myschema' AND TABLE_NAME ='mytable' \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: def
   TABLE_SCHEMA: myschema
     TABLE_NAME: mytable
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: InnoDB
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Dynamic
     TABLE_ROWS: 262354
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 114
    DATA_LENGTH: 30015488
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 0
   INDEX_LENGTH: 0
      DATA_FREE: 4194304
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2022-05-17 12:00:32
    UPDATE_TIME: 2022-05-17 06:00:37
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS: 
  TABLE_COMMENT: 
1 row in set (0,04 sec)
```

As you can see, it looks like the table was created ***after*** it was updated. Any idea what can cause this?

**EDIT:** Here's the schema:

```
show create table myschema.mytable \G;

| mytable | CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
  `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable \G`. I am interested in seeing if the table has indexes (besides the PRIMARY KEY).

Comment: Also, please run `SET innodb_stats_on_metadata = 'ON'; SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydb LIKE 'mytable';` Then, run the original SELECT. Did the CREATE_TIME or UPDATE_TIME change ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Added the schema. No indexes beside the PK. `innodb_stats_on_metadata` was already enabled, and the timestamps did not change.

Comment: Also worth noting (and I should have mentioned this first) is that this table is replaced daily with the following steps:

CREATE TABLE mytable_new; LOAD DATA ....; RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_old, mytable_new TO mytable;

Would this explain the timestamps? It feels like it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it shouldn't. Unfortunately, I strongly feel there is a bug.

I created a test in the Windows version of MySQL 8.0.23

## TEST CODE

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
USE dbasa_duru
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
  `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
DO SLEEP(5);
CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
DO SLEEP(3);
INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
DO SLEEP(3);
RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
DO SLEEP(3);
SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
```

Please note how I put `DO SLEEP(3);` to make sure we see distinct timestamps between operations.

I ran this multiple times, the UPDATE_TIME seems to be stuck on the timestamp `2022-05-18 09:28:56`, the time I began running this test.

Here is the session where I ran the test multiple times

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version       | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| innodb_version          | 8.0.23                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions  |                               |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                 | 8.0.23                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib    | 1.2.11                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE dbasa_duru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->   `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:38:46 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:38:51 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
    -> ('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:38:46 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:38:51 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:38:51 | NULL        |
| t1_old     | 2022-05-18 09:38:46 | NULL        |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version       | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| innodb_version          | 8.0.23                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions  |                               |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                 | 8.0.23                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib    | 1.2.11                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE dbasa_duru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->   `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:43:30 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:43:35 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
    -> ('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:43:30 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:43:35 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:43:35 | NULL        |
| t1_old     | 2022-05-18 09:43:30 | NULL        |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version       | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| innodb_version          | 8.0.23                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions  |                               |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                 | 8.0.23                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib    | 1.2.11                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE dbasa_duru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->   `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:45:22 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:45:27 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
    -> ('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:45:22 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:45:27 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:45:27 | NULL        |
| t1_old     | 2022-05-18 09:45:22 | NULL        |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version       | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| innodb_version          | 8.0.23                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions  |                               |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                 | 8.0.23                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib    | 1.2.11                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE dbasa_duru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->   `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.07 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:46:51 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:46:56 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
    -> ('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:46:51 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:46:56 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:46:56 | NULL        |
| t1_old     | 2022-05-18 09:46:51 | NULL        |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version       | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| innodb_version          | 8.0.23                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions  |                               |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                 | 8.0.23                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib    | 1.2.11                        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dbasa_duru;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE dbasa_duru
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
    -> (
    ->   `app_id` char(27) NOT NULL,
    ->   `ref_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` decimal(10,5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`ref_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(5);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1_new LIKE t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.12 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:47:10 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:47:15 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1_new (app_id,ref_id,value) VALUES
    -> ('APP01',5,10.5),('APP02',6,12.6),('APP03',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP04',5,10.5),('APP05',6,12.6),('APP06',5,14.7),
    -> ('APP07',5,10.5),('APP08',6,12.6),('APP09',5,14.7);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:47:10 | NULL                |
| t1_new     | 2022-05-18 09:47:15 | 2022-05-18 09:28:56 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_old, t1_new TO t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE table_schema='dbasa_duru' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t1_old','t1_new');
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| t1         | 2022-05-18 09:47:15 | NULL        |
| t1_old     | 2022-05-18 09:47:10 | NULL        |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

While the resulting behavior of my test is slightly different from yours, it is just as bad because the timestamp `2022-05-18 09:28:56` keeps reappearing long after I did the initial test.

There has to be some bug regarding the information_schema. If I got this error in Windows, this bug most also exist in other OS versions of MySQL 8.0.23.

You should file a bug report. Chances are, Oracle might say it is a feature and you should code around it. It the very least, information_schema.tables is a little unstable.

Comment: Indeed, it does look like a bug. I'll report it upstream. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is already reported bug [(90219)](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90219) for that. I've tested on our enviroment like these steps:

1: Create Table
[image: Info section after Table Creation]
As you can see, there is no update date on information field.

2: DML Operation such as insert:
[image: Info section after DML query]

3: Table Alter operation
[image: Info section after alter table operation]

After alter operation update time still same but creation time renewed. Probably alter commands drop and creates table, hence create date section updated. But MySQL keeps DML and watermark statistics on different place. It's ridiculous but I hope there is a logical explanation behind of it.

Our data architect team getting trouble on their data catalog product because of this update time < create time situation